# Facebook SDK 3.8.0 share dialog: manage the cancellation by the user

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developing an application that uses the Facebook share dialog.
Here's my dialog implementation:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                        .setLink(playStoreLink)
                        .setName(appName)
                        .setDescription("I'm here with "+name)
                        .setPicture(linkPicture)
                        .build();
                    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

And here's the `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
                Utilities.GeneralDismissableDialog(context, String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Now if the user press the back button, the `onComplete` method is invoked, so the application prints the success message "Success!".
I read the dcomunetation but i didn't find any suggestions.

How can i manage the cancellation by the user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335781/android-facebook-sdk-3-8-0-share-dialog-manage-the-cancellation-by-the-user Please delete one of your answers as they are duplicate.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the advisory